# How can I cache OR serve custom web fonts faster in Asp .Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fonts, webfonts, page-load-time

I am working on a website and it is pretty fast actually but the custom web fonts are preventing it to be faster. The web site is loaded about 4 seconds but the fonts takes 2 seconds to be loaded, is there a way to load it faster?

I placed the web fonts as woff format in my project folder as static files.
and i just marked the static files as below.

```
<staticcontent>
  <clientcache cachecontrolmode="UseMaxAge" cachecontrolmaxage="365.00:00:00" />
</staticcontent>
```

This adds an expired header to the files which is Ok but I'm looking for the other ways to load them faster if there is an one.

Comment: Until the browser has cached the item, the first load will always be longer. If you consistently see long load times then you should watch the network requests (with the browser's dev tools) for your fonts to verify that those items really are using the cached copy.

Comment: I think the browser never caches these items actually. Here a picture shows the load times of the fonts after the second load of the page; https://dbhub.blob.core.windows.net/live/stack.PNG

Comment: So examine the network headers for those items to be sure you've setup caching correctly.

Comment: Also check that your browser doesn't disable cache. I often do this for my development browser. And if you're starting this up with F5 debug there's a good chance you're getting fresh copies each time you run your site.